# Stay indoors vs stay indoor

Tags: phrase-usage

From my understanding, "*Bob stayed indoors*" is a correct expression, while "*Bob stayed indoor*" is incorrect. Why is the latter incorrect? The term *indoor* is an adjective, and the verb *stay* is often followed by an adjective (e.g., "*Let's stay focused.*")

Comment: OALD gives the information: indoor, adjective, only before noun as in indoor games.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/indoor?q=indoor

Comment: Indoor**s** (formerly within-doors) appears to be the survival of an adverbial genitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *STAY* creates a space for a Subject and a Predicative Complement:

- The elephants stayed awake.

Here the Subject is the phrase *the elephants* and the Predicative Complement is the word *awake*. A Predicative Complement usually describes the Subject or Object of a verb. With the verb *STAY* the Predicative Complement describes the Subject. So, in this example, *awake* describes the elephants.

Predicative Complements can be noun phrases, adjective phrases or preposition phrases:

- The elephants stayed **friends**. (noun phrase)
- The elephants stayed **vigilant**. (adjective phrase)
- The elephants stayed **in the kitchen**. (preposition phrase)

Predicative Complements cannot normally be adverb phrases:

- *The elephants stayed largely. (Ungrammatical)
- *That woman is beautifully. (Ungrammatical)

These sentences are ungrammatical if the adverbs are understood a Predicative Complements.

**The Original Poster's Example**

The word *indoor* can be considered an adjective. However, it is an attributive only adjective. We can only use it before nouns. We cannot use it as a Predicative Complement:

- The elephants want an indoor swimming pool.
- *The elephant was indoor. (ungrammatical)

Because we are making a sentence with the verb *STAY*, we need a word or phrase that can function as a Predicative Complement. We cannot use the attributive adjective *indoor*. But we can, of course, use the preposition *indoors*. This word looks very similar to the adjective, but it is a preposition:

- The elephants stayed indoors.
- Bob stayed indoors.

---

**Grammar reference** Teachers and very high level students: you can read about *indoors* and other prepositions like this that occur without following nouns in [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=628&zoom=auto,-242,851).

Comment: I've never heard _indoors_ described as a preposition. I know there is now a model which says that prepositions don't have to take NP objects, but one that never takes an object? I would say (in fact I did) that _indoors_ is an adverb, and like _down_ and _away_ it can be a predicative complement.

Comment: @ColinFine You need to get out more! ;-) Intransitive propositions are about as old as the hills (well, at least a hundred years old). They're standard for the bulk of modern grammarians - and they're certainly much easier for language learners to deal with. You can see *indoors* listed here in [the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p. 614](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=628&zoom=auto,-242,851) along with many other intransitive ones.

Answer (score 6):

*Indoor* is an adjective, but is only ever used attributively (preceding a noun phrase), not predicatively (following a verb). Most adjectives can be used either way, but not all. Another example of an adjective which cannot be used predicatively is *former*.

*Indoors* is an adverb (of place), and can follow a verb  like *stay*.